# Copy displayed picture on a TPanel into a TImage

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, mplayer

I've embedded MPlayer video results into `TPanel` successfully, BUT can't copy `TPanel` results into a `TImage`.

ONLY the normal picture of `TPanel` is copied into `TImage` :

[image]

Embedding is performed using piping and MPlayer wid command line parameters. MPlayer using `TPanel` handle to display results.

The following snippets tested, but just normal `TPanel` picture copied into `TImage`:

```
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.CopyRect(
    Rect(0, 0, Image1.Width-1, Image1.Height-1),
    TMyPanel(Panel1).Canvas,     //TMyPanel is an empty class to access canvas property 
    Rect(0, 0, Panel1.Width-1, Panel1.Height-1)
  );
```

and this:

```
Function PanelToBmp ( Panel:TPanel):TBitmap;
VAR
  bmp : tBitmap;
  DC  : HDC;
Begin
  bmp := tBitmap.Create;
  bmp.width := Panel.Width;
  bmp.Height := Panel.Height;
  DC := GetDc ( Panel.Handle );
  Bitblt(bmp.canvas.handle, 0, 0, Panel.Width, Panel.Height, Dc, 0, 0, NOTSRCCOPY);
  Releasedc (Panel.handle,dc);
  result := bmp;
End;
```

Comment: I don't know MPlayer in particular, but often video is rendered a little bit differently and you can't take a 'normal' screenshot of it. I did find some information about MPlayer which suggests you need to start it with a specific parameter, after which you can let MPlayer make screenshots itself. Maybe there are ways to send such commands to your embedded MPlayer? See [this](http://www.systutorials.com/2990/taking-screenshot-in-mplayer/) and [this](http://mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2004-August/047721.html).

Answer (score 1):

You also can copy through the clipboard, try this:

`uses ClipBrd;`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lBmp: TBitmap;
begin
  lBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    lBmp.SetSize(Panel1.ClientWidth, Panel1.ClientHeight);
    BitBlt(lBmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Panel1.ClientWidth, Panel1.ClientHeight, TMyPanel(Panel1).Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    Clipboard.Assign(lBmp);

   Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign( lBmp );
  finally
    lBmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the script, but doesn't worked. Like other scripts only show picture of a normal Panel.